# How can I return html or json with deno?

Tags: deno

I would like to know if a Deno app can return json or a web page depending on the url. If so, which response type would I use? I know for json it's (I'm using Drash):

```
response_output: "application/json"
```

(for Drash.Http.Server)

Can I add something to allow returning a web page and, if so, how?

I know to return json it's like this:

```
this.response.body = myjson;
return this.response;
```

How can I do the same thing to return a web page?

Thanks for your answers.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

use `response_output` with `text/html`

```js
import { Drash } from "https://deno.land/x/drash/mod.ts";

class HomeResource extends Drash.Http.Resource {

  static paths = ["/"];

  public GET() {
    this.response.body = "GET request received!";
    if (this.request.accepts("text/html")) {
      // Your HTML here
      this.response.body = "<body>GET request received!</body>";
    }
    return this.response;
  }
}

const server = new Drash.Http.Server({
  response_output: "text/html",
  resources: [HomeResource],
});
```

`response_output` sets the default `Content-Type`, but you can change it on a specific route by doing:

```
this.response.headers.set("Content-Type", "text/html");
```

```js
 public GET() {
    this.response.headers.set("Content-Type", "application/json");
    this.response.body = JSON.stringify({ foo: 'bar' });
    if (this.request.accepts("text/html")) {
      this.response.headers.set("Content-Type", "text/html");
      this.response.body = "<body>GET request received!</body>";
    }
    return this.response;
  }
```

Comment: Ok but here the server can only return html no ? How can I return json and html depending of the ressource ? Like have `response_output:"text/html" and "application/json"`

Comment: check the updated answer, use: `this.response.headers.set("Content-Type", "text/html");` or `application/json` depending on the route.

Comment: Perfect thanks, and if I want to return a full html page with icon and everything else rather than a simple text

Comment: a "full html page" is simple text. If you want to serve static content such as images, check https://drash.land/docs/#/tutorials/servers/serving-static-paths