# How can I return html or json with Deno (oak)?

Tags: typescript, deno, oak

I've seen: [How can I return html or json with deno?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/62209840/how-can-i-return-html-or-json-with-deno) but I needed an answer for Oak - Posting below.

Answer (score 3):

It would be something along the lines of:

```
import { Application } from 'https://deno.land/x/oak/mod.ts'
import { Router } from 'https://deno.land/x/oak/mod.ts'
const port = 8000

// Handler
const getTestResponse = ({ response }: { response: any }) => {
    response.status = 200
    response.headers.set("Content-Type", "application/json") // set to html if you want
    response.body = {
        data: "test"
    }
}

const app = new Application()

// Router
const router = new Router()
router.get('/api/v1/test', getTestResponse)
app.use(router.routes())
app.use(router.allowedMethods())

console.log(`Server running on port ${port}`)

await app.listen({ port })
```

- Uses JSON by default for the response (no need to set explicitly like in the example) - I just wanted to show that you can change it.

**Note**: *please split the handler, routes and the main code to different modules in the real world, so others won't be pissed at you :)*

Comment: I had the same problem. `response.headers.set("Content-Type", "text/html")` was the missing piece of the puzzle - thanks very much!

Answer (score 1):

Alternative Solution:

```js
router.get('/test/', async (ctx) => {
    ctx.response.type = "application/json";
    ctx.response.body = {test: 1};
});
```